# Systemd-Networkd BindCarrier failed with "Unknown lvalue"

Tags: networking, systemd, vlan

Currently I'm trying to setup a bond network with vlan with systemd-networkd. Unfortunately the service gives me the error message "Unknown lvalue 'BindCarrier' in section 'Network'" for the bond1.network configuration file.

Here are my configuration files:

```
### eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
IPForward=yes
Bond=bond1

### bond1.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=bond1
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
TransmitHashPolicy=layer3+4
MIIMonitorSec=1s
LACPTransmitRate=fast

### bond1.network
[Match]
Name=bond1

[Network]
BindCarrier=eth0
VLAN=vlan10
VLAN=vlan20
VLAN=vlan30

### vlan<10|20|30>.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=vlan<10|20|30>
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=<4010|4020|4030>

### vlan<10|20|30>.network
[Match]
Name=vlan<10|20|30>

[Network]
Bridge=br<10|20|30>

### br<10|20|30>.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=br<10|20|30>
Kind=bridge

### br<10|20|30>.network
[Match]
Name=br<10|20|30>

[Network]
Address=172.29.<10|20|30>.11/24
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option was introduced in systemd v220 and is not available in your older version.

Comment: Ah thank you. That was the information I was missing.